# Access EL function in Adobe CQ 5.6, TLD not picked up

Tags: jsp, el, aem

Can anyone give guidance for accessing an EL function from within a JSP that is deployed on Adobe CQ 5.6?

My JSP sits in a package, while I have the EL function (static method in Java class) and the associated TLD located in a separate OSGi bundle.  Both are installed to Adobe CQ.
The POM for the bundle does export the relevant Java package:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-Name>AIB UI Bundle</Bundle-Name>
            <Export-Package>
                mypackage.*
            </Export-Package>
            <Include-Resource>
                {maven-resources}
            </Include-Resource>
            <Embed-Dependency>joda-convert;scope=compile|runtime,joda-time;scope=compile|runtime,</Embed-Dependency>
            <Bundle-Resource>/META-INF/tags</Bundle-Resource>
            <Sling-Bundle-Resource>/META-INF/tags</Sling-Bundle-Resource>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, when the JSP is processed, the call to the EL function fails.

The error reads:
**File "/apps/aib/mortgage/components/page/main/utilityFunction" not found**

---

My code is below.  All help gratefully received.

Regards,
Ken.

EL Function class, located in OSGi bundle, `src/main/java/mypackage/UtilityFunction.java`:

`package mypackage;`

```
public class UtilityFunction {

private UtilityFunction() {
...
}

   public static String displayBuildNumber() {
   // Do processing
   }
}
```

---

TLD, located in same OSGi bundle, `src/main/resources/META-INF/utilityExpressionLanguageFunctions.tld`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encodeing="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<uri>utilityFunction</uri>
<function>
<name>displayBuildNumber</name>
<function-class>mypackage.UtilityFunction</function-class>
<function-signature>String displayBuildNumber()</function-signature>
</function>
</taglib>
```

---

JSP, located at `/apps/myproj/components/page/main/head.jsp`:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" %>
<%@taglib prefix="cq" uri="http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/1.0" %>
<%@taglib prefix="utils" uri="utilityFunction" %>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="<%=properties.get("p_metaKeywords","") %>" />
<meta name="description" content="<%=properties.get("p_metaDescription","") %>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

<title>My Application ${utils:displayBuildNumber()}</title>
<cq:include script="/libs/wcm/core/components/init/init.jsp"/>
<cq:include script="/libs/wcm/core/browsermap/browsermap.jsp" />
<cq:includeClientLib css="jquery-ui" />
<cq:includeClientLib js="cq.jquery, cq.foundation-main, cq.shared, forms-overlay, jquery-ui,cq.jquery.ui" />
</head>

<cq:defineObjects />
```

Comment: If the problem is not with your package getting installed, I think the uri might need to be more specific like this `<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="WEB-INF/custom.tld"%>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a complete address for the uri value. Consider the following fully functioning example:

//In the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Export-Package>
            //Packages.....
            </Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>
            *;resolution:=optional
            </Import-Package>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
            <Sling-Test-Regexp>.*Test</Sling-Test-Regexp>
            <Include-Resource>
                META-INF/my-tags.tld=target/classes/META-INF/my-tags.tld
            </Include-Resource>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

//In the tld file

```
<description>My Test Taglib</description>
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>cq-common</short-name>
<uri>http://taglib.cq.mycompany.se/taglibs/my-tags/1.0</uri>

<function>
    <name>doSomeThing</name>
    <function-class>com.my.company.SomeUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>String doSomeThing(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
```

//In the jsp file

```
<%@taglib prefix="mytags" uri="http://taglib.cq.mycompany.se/taglibs/my-tags/1.0"%>
${mytags:doSomeThing(stringValueOfSomething)}
```

Notice the uri value located with a fully qualified address at two places:
In the tld file:

```
<uri>http://taglib.cq.mycompany.se/taglibs/my-tags/1.0</uri>
```

and in the jsp file:

```
<%@taglib prefix="mytags" uri="http://taglib.cq.mycompany.se/taglibs/my-tags/1.0"%>
```

Hope that will solve the problem